# .net: How to execute a stored procedure with a nullable parameter in c#?

Tags: .net, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, nullable

How to execute a stored procedure with a nullable parameter in c#?

**EDIT**:

Actually, I've written below code. As you can see, status parameter is a nullable value type. 
Is it correct? or not?

```
public void LoadAll(DataTable tb, int? status=null)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = this.connectionString;

                using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.CommandText = "USP_OrganizationChartSelect";
                    SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(command);
                    command.Parameters["@Status"].Value = status.HasValue ? status : null;
                    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                        connection.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                    tb.Clear();
                    adapter.Fill(tb);
                    adapter.Dispose();
                    adapter = null;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: We need a little more detail here: which database server?

Comment: You should put a `using()` around your data adapter as well.

Answer (score 4):

You could try [`DBNull.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.aspx) instead of `null` or omit the parameter when the nullable has no value entirely.

Comment: you mean that I should put Deriveparameter in an if block ?

Comment: I havn't done a lot of work with SqlCommand and Datasets but I would suggest trying the if test like: if (status.HasValue) { command.Parameters["@Status"].Value = status }

Comment: what you suggested (using DBNull.value) generates an error indicating that there is no implicit conversion between int? and DBNull,

Comment: How about: command.Parameters["@Status"].Value = (object)status ?? DBNull.Value;

Answer (score 0):

If the parameter is nullable, it must be a value type. Suppose you have an int nullable parameter, then you can pass it this way..

```
  int? nullableParam = null;
  nullableParam = 10; //set the value if any
  //Pass nullableParam to your sp call.
```

Comment: use the GetValueOrDefault method of the nullable object or its default value.

Comment: default value for an int  = 0  not what we have suggested (null)

Answer (score 0):

you can check the nullable value in your sp like below:

```
select * from table
where (code = @code or @code is null)
```

by this solution if @code be null then this condition will not apply.

Comment: A tidier way of doing this is:

`where code = ISNULL(@code, code)`

If your parameter is null, it uses the value of the column itself for the compairison.